# How to format calculated land size in excel

Tags: excel

I'm calculating column sum in excel like this `=SUM(A1:A10)` and also B1..10 and C1..10. Column A represents "h" (hectare - my English is not so good, so please don't judge), B is "a" (are - like acre but not acre :) and C is "m" (square meters).
My sum ends up something like this in columns A B C -> 3 105 245 respectively, but I need it formatted to be like this A B C -> 4 07 45.
What is the code for that? 
Again, sorry I don't know English that well and I don't know how that calculation is called in English so I don't know how to google it.

Comment: Shouldn't 3ha 105a 245m² be 4ha 7a 45m²?

Comment: yes, I noticed that and edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get hectare (`F2`):

```
=A2+QUOTIENT(B2*100+C2,10000)
```

or

```
=QUOTIENT(A2*10000+B2*100+C2,10000)
```

To get are (`G2`):

```
=QUOTIENT(MOD(B2*100+C2,10000),100)
```

To get square meters (`H2`):

```
=MOD(C2,100)
```

Result:

[image]

Instead of `A2`, `B2` and `C2` use your sums of `A1:A10` and so on.